# Custom directive jquery-ui datepicker in Vuejs 2.0

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I had a directive in Vuejs 1.0 when ever I wanted to attach a datepicker(jquery-ui) in any field.

```
datepicker: {

        bind: function () {

            var vm = this.vm;

            var key = this.expression;

            $(this.el).datepicker({

                minDate: vm.$parent.startingDate,

                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',

                onSelect: function (date) {

                    vm.$set(key, date);

                }

            });

        },

        update: function (val) {

            $(this.el).datepicker('setDate', val);

        }

    }
```

This code doesn't work with Vuejs 2.0 because the directive drastically changed. Before I'll try to build a component for this one I would love to know how you can do something like this in Vuejs 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2873 Directive interface change.

Directives no longer have instances - this means there's no more this inside directive hooks and bind, update and unbind now receives everything as arguments.

The best way to do this in vue 2 is really to make a custom component.

Comment: I'll try the component way. Thanks!